# systemctl cannot disable services, displays upstart errors

Tags: boot, 16.04, upstart, systemd, puppet

On my Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) server, I cannot disable services from autostarting at boot. I get these error messages:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable puppet.service
...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
```

Next time I boot the server, "puppet agent" is running automatically.

I am guessing (from the error messages) that my server is in some weird intermediate state between systemd (which is running) and Upstart. FYI, this server used to run Ubuntu 14 (pre-systemd) and has been upgraded to 15.04, 15.10, and 16.04.

It appears that systemd is running and upstart is not:

```
$ ps uax|grep init | grep -v grep
root         1  0.0  0.0 119780  6000 ?        Ss   May20   0:04 /sbin/init
$ ps uax|grep upstart|grep -v grep
$ ps uax|grep systemd|grep -v grep
root       279  0.0  0.0  35368  3276 ?        Ss   May20   0:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       306  0.0  0.0  45956  5384 ?        Ss   May20   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
systemd+   703  0.0  0.0 100324  2532 ?        Ssl  May20   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root       709  0.0  0.0  20100  2824 ?        Ss   May20   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       716  0.0  0.0  29880  1564 ?        Ss   May20   0:00 /sbin/cgmanager -m name=systemd
message+   727  0.0  0.0  52848  5668 ?        Ss   May20   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

I read the [SystemdForUpstartUsers wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) and confirmed that the packages `systemd-sysv` and `ubuntu-standard` are installed, and `upstart-sysv`  is not. So I appear to have the right packages. I've also googled (in vain) these error messages but have not found a solution.

Full error message:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable puppet.service
Synchronizing state of puppet.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable puppet
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `puppet' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `puppet' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `puppet' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `puppet' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
```

Any help appreciated!!

**Updated 2016-05-24:**

If I remove the associated `/etc/init.d` script (such as `/etc/init.d/puppet` in the above example), the error messages go away. Presumably systemd is using `/lib/systemd/system/puppet.service` instead...?

Comment: For the record: You want https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429032/ .